# Changing numbers that precede strings with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have some files with many lines which have one of two formats:

```
filename 8724.609 13204.0636961952836 8.8970 xjf

ghw5ra_120411x_9999.splits 5516.291992 16028.341273612765160 25.333 reb  -chan 0 -subint 0 -snr 5.6939
```

In either case, I want to change the numbers that immediately precede the three letters (in these cases "xjf" and "reb") with a set number (e.g. 99.999).

I know that I can do this using regular expressions, and I think that I can substitute the three letters with something like:

x = filename 8724.609 13204.0636961952836 8.8970 xjf

```
re.sub(r" [a-z]{3}", " abc", x)
```

But I'm not sure how I change the numbers that precede the three letters.

Comment: In what way do you want to change those numbers? Maybe regex isn't the right tool for your job.

Comment: The `[ ]?\d+(.\d+)? (?=[A-Za-z]{3}[ ]?)` regex matches numbers before words that consist of more than 3 letters, andmay also match non-numbers, too, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/En8bUI/3). Why did you accept the wrong solution? Or did I get the requirements wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below:

```
re.sub('[ ]?\d+(.\d+)? (?=[A-Za-z]{3}[ ]?)', ' 99.99 ', text)
```

To break it down:
I search for a space digits space with this:

```
 [ ]?\d+(.)?\d+
```

Then using a lookahead assertion you search for 3 characters and may or may not end with a space:

```
(?=[A-Za-z]{3}[ ]?
```

Finally the sub would replace this returned value with what you provided (99.99) in this case.

Comment: Try it with `123 abc` and `abc 1 def`

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
x = re.sub(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s+[a-z]{3}\b)', '99.999', x)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xqiQF5/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B)%3F(%3F%3D%5Cs%2B%5Ba-z%5D%7B3%7D%5Cb)):

[image]

**Details**

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional fractional part: `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?=\s+[a-z]{3}\b)` - a positive lookahead that requires 1+ whitespaces, three lowercase ASCII letters followed with a word boundary to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/RNaoPr):

```
import re
x = """filename 8724.609 13204.0636961952836 8.8970 xjf
ghw5ra_120411x_9999.splits 5516.291992 16028.341273612765160 25.333 reb  -chan 0 -subint 0 -snr 5.6939"""
x = re.sub(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s+[a-z]{3}\b)', '99.999', x)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
filename 8724.609 13204.0636961952836 99.999 xjf
ghw5ra_120411x_9999.splits 5516.291992 16028.341273612765160 99.999 reb  -chan 0 -subint 0 -snr 5.6939
```